# How can I convert text files with an unusual extension (.1 .2 .3 .4) into an image file?

Tags: file-extension

Duplicate file names aren't saved as **abc (1).jpeg**, but instead **abc.jpeg.1**. They're inaccessible as an image; they're just text instead.

I've tried a bunch of websites and so far only [convertio](https://convertio.co/) has worked, but it has a 10 file limit. They do turn into images, but it would be nice to find a website that doesn't limit conversions or some other method.

Comment: What is saving these files? Where are they coming from? What OS? I would guess that you really want to look at the application creating these files and solve the problem there, but that's not what you've written here.

Comment: @music2myear ok so its not my archive so i dont know the first two but im on windows 11. 

all i know is that its an archive on Tim32 with all the attachments of a defunct forum. funny thing, on the same forum but on a different page (the profile pictures of the members), the files are named the exact same BUT download and open up as image files...weird

Comment: @music2myear That's what `wget` does when you tell it to save a page with its resources (`--page-requisites`), and ask it not to build out the folder structure for the different resources (`--no-directories`). Both _/images/logo.png_ and _/images/press/logo.png_ would save to your CWD, and `wget` appends the number to the file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the extension back to the correct one. Your system doesn't know what a .1 file is, it does know what a .jpeg or .jpg is. They don't need converting.

Whatever is responsible for renaming the duplicate names is badly wrong. It ought to know to put the number before the extension, not after it - otherwise this issue will arise, on any filesystem, any OS.